# Did Darren Wilson make this statement?

Tags: politics, quotes, police

This statement is attributed to Darren Wilson, the policeman who [shot Michael Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_of_Michael_Brown).

> “It is with deep sympathy that I come to you today. What happen, has happened and I can’t do anything about it. I wouldn't change anything because I felt as though I would have died if I didn't take action on that black kid. This has nothing to do with race. But in all honesty I don't think he would have attacked me like that if he was of a different background. He was very aggressive. I wanted to get those cigarillo’s back from him that he stole, but he simply wouldn’t let them go. He punched me several times and it felt like a huge black gorilla was pouncing on my face. I thought my face was going to explode. As you can tell from the photos, they are very gruesome and I wish this on no one. I am truly sorry that I killed Michael Brown. I didn’t want to shoot him so many times. I felt maybe two or even three shots would have done the job. I have a child and I wouldn’t want my child to go through what Brown went through, it was just an awful situation. But I do apologize for everything if my actions hurt anyone. This situation has made me a better man; I am just grateful that I can now watch my child grow. So please I ask all of you for peace.”

Is this statement genuine?  In internet searching I have only found [one source](http://www.hiphophangover.com/index.php/14-world-news1/66-darren-wilson-issues-apology-to-mike-brown) for it and it does not seem a very legitimate source.

Comment: For what it is worth, it would appear to conflict with the [statement issued by his lawyers](http://www.vox.com/xpress/2014/11/24/7278975/read-darren-wilson-releases-statement-on-grand-jury-decision-via-his). "Any commentary on the matter will be done in the appropriate venue and not through the media".

Comment: Where did you get this quote? Is this claim notable?

Comment: It appeared on twitter yesterday. https://twitter.com/Iunaticsfringe/status/537708065773346816 
https://twitter.com/ultrasadgirl/status/537411753521324032 
https://twitter.com/jewyslut/status/537412193718128640 
https://twitter.com/iAm_Myy/status/537352138608091137
just some examples.

Comment: @AlexC The most widely propagated, i.e. retweeted, was https://twitter.com/iAm_Myy/status/537352138608091137 She prefaced it by saying "apparent", and responded to dozens of inquiries by politely saying she wasn't certain of the quote's validity or source, and to wait until further information from the media became available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Darren Wilson didn't make that statement as it contains factual inaccuracies. First, regarding this,

> I have a child and I wouldn’t want my child to go through what Brown
>   went through, it was just an awful situation. But I do apologize for
>   everything if my actions hurt anyone. This situation has made me a
>   better man; I am just grateful that I can now watch my child grow.

Darren Wilson has no children, neither by his first wife nor his current wife nor another woman, see [For better or worse: Killer cop Darren Wilson MARRIED a fellow police officer last month](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2847548/Ferguson-cop-Darren-Wilson-married-fellow-police-officer-month.html)  via *Daily Mail UK* (25 November 2014):

> Wilson married his first wife Ashley Brown in Old Monroe, Missouri in
>   October 2011 but divorced last year. They had no children.

Next, both CNN and Black News quote an **[ABC News video](http://www.nbcnews.com/storyline/michael-brown-shooting/darren-wilson-says-he-feels-remorse-michael-brown-killing-ferguson-n256511)**,

> Wilson told ABC that he was sorry for the loss of life but that he was
>   simply doing his job and following his training.

Via **[Black News](http://www.blacknews.com/news/officer-darren-wilson-abc-news-interview-conscious-clear-michael-brown101.html)**,

> Officer Darren Wilson Defends Shooting Michael Brown — Says “I’m
>   Sorry… But My Conscience is Clear”

Via **[CNN](http://www.cnn.com/2014/11/25/us/darren-wilson-interview/)**,

> Darren Wilson says he's sorry but his conscience is clear

I cannot find any source for the verbiage in the excerpt, other than *Hip Hop Hangover*. In fact, Darren Wilson does has not issued *any* apology for the shooting at all. The **[Ferguson Chief of Police apologized to Michael Brown's family](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/post-nation/wp/2014/09/25/ferguson-police-chief-to-michael-browns-family-im-truly-sorry/)** in September 2014, but Wilson has not done so.

Comment: @ChrisW I just saw that now, in a new Daily Mail UK post. His wife, age 37, is expecting her first child. Wilson is not yet a father, but point taken.

Comment: This is the best source yet, [Darren Wilson reveals he is about to become a father for the first time with new cop wife](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2850205/Darren-Wilson-reveals-father-time-new-cop-wife-exclusive-interview-following-Michael-Brown-shooting.html). There is no mention of a "huge black gorilla" etc.